# Ejabberd and Conversations using OMEMO

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm new to XMPP Servers and have setup a ejabberd server 18.09 under Windows 7 and I'm using Conversations 2.3.4+fcr as client.
Now I want to use OMEMO and I have no success. Conversations says in its server info, that XEP-0163 has failed and when I want to write a OMEMO encrypted message Conversations is complaining about missing device list.

I understand that OMEMO encryption is based on the existing device list in ejabberd server. Ejabberd knows the device, I can see Conversations.something as device in the online user list.

Configuration file of ejabberd is like this:

```
force_node_config: 
"eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.*": 
access_model: whitelist
```

Conversations says in CATLOG:

```
AxolotlService: Have no target devices in PEP!
```

At the moment I'm running out of ideas, any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

The default config for 18.12 came with this in the config

```
force_node_config:
  ## Change from "whitelist" to "open" to enable OMEMO support
  ## See https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2425
```